# Massive slowdown showing settings for a VM in Hyper-V manager, using certain Hyper-V powershell cmdlets. Why?

Tags: hyper-v, slowdown

I'm seeing a massive slowdown when I right click on a VM in Hyper-V manager and show its properties. It takes 35 seconds to fully populate. Note in the screenshot where parts of the properties are still "Loading..."

[image: Most property categories still loading...]

Similarly, running certain cmdlets like `Get-VMSecurity` on a VM will take over 10 seconds to return.

What can cause this massive slowdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there can be different causes, the solution on two different machines for me was to simply create a Hyper-V virtual switch called `Default Switch` in the `Virtual Switch Manager`. This completely eliminated this problem.

[image: Creating "Default Switch"]

I had been hitting this on an old dev machine and was excited to move to my new machine where I expected things to be better. Imagine my consternation when they weren't.

After noticing things were super-snappy on some ancient 7-year-old hardware, I dug into the event viewer during the slowdown. It revealed that Hyper-V was constantly creating/initializing/using/destroying a switch called "Default Switch".

It seems many Hyper-V management operations require the presence of a switch named `Default Switch`, and if it doesn't exist, it is created and then destroyed as needed, causing massive slowdown.

My dev machines both lacked the default `Default Switch`, which does NAT network sharing. It was present at first, but after creating other virtual switches, it ceased to exist. I created an internal switch named `Default Switch` as shown above. Now the properties for a VM show up instantly in the Hyper-V Manager GUI, and the powershell cmdlets are snappy.